# ggplot scatterplot and lines

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I have some biological data for two individuals, and I graph it using R as a scatterplot using ggplot like this:

```
p1<-ggplot(data, aes(meth_matrix$sample1, meth_matrix$sample3)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_minimal()
```

which works perfect, but I want to add lines to it: the abline that divides the scatterplot in half:

```
p1  + geom_abline(color="blue")
```

and my question is: how can I draw two red lines parallel to that diagonal (y intercept would be 0.2, slope would be the same as the blue line) ??

Also: how can I draw the difference of both samples in a similar scatterplot (it will look like a horizontal scatterplot) with ggplot? right now I can only do it with plot like:

```
dif_samples<-meth_matrix$sample1- meth_matrix$sample3
plot(dif_samples, main="difference", 
     xlab="CpGs ", ylab="Methylation ", pch=19)
```

(also I'd like adding the horizontal blue line and the red lines paralllel to the blue line)

Please help!!!

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify slopes and intercepts in the `geom_abline()` function. I'll use the iris dataset that comes with `ggplot2` to illustrate:

```r
# I'll use the iris dataset. I normalise by dividing the variables by their max so that
# a line through the origin will be visible
library(ggplot2)
p1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length/max(Sepal.Length), Sepal.Width/max(Sepal.Width))) + 
  geom_point() + theme_minimal()

# Draw lines by specifying their slopes and intercepts. since all lines
# share a slope I just give one insted of a vector of slopes
p1 + geom_abline(intercept = c(0, .2, -.2), slope = 1,  
                 color = c("blue", "red", "red"))
```

[image]

I'm not as clear on exactly what you want for the second plot, but you can plot differences directly in the call to `ggplot()` and you can add horizontal lines with `geom_hline()`:

```r
# Now lets plot the difference between sepal length and width
# for each observation

p2 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = 1:nrow(iris), 
                       y = (Sepal.Length - Sepal.Width) )) + 
  geom_point() + theme_minimal()

# we'll add horizontal lines -- you can pick values that make sense for your problem
p2 + geom_hline(yintercept = c(3, 3.2, 2.8),  
                 color = c("blue", "red", "red"))
```

[image]

Created on 2018-03-21 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thank you so much! this is exactly what I wanted to do